# CSS not connecting to HTML

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having issues with getting my CSS file to be read by the HTML file. I have linked the two, but for some reason the results are not showing. I have saved the two filed in the same folder on my server, but for some reason i keep hitting a road block. What do you think the problem could be? Thankyou!

```
<head>
    <meta Campus DrinkThink/> 
    <title>Campus DrinkThink</title> <!--this is the link to the style sheet--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="sftp://ec2-user@23.21.112.84/var/www/html/campusdrinkthink.css" /> 
</head>
```

Comment: **Please show us your code**.  What do you see in Firebug?

Comment: Are you sure that your browser supports **sftp** schema? Mozilla Firefox 12 - doesn't. Try to open `sftp://ec2-user@23.21.112.84/var/www/html/campusdrinkthink.css` directly in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

99.9999999999999% of cases, the path to your CSS file is incorrect.

In your case, you're pointing to the FTP server rather than the location on your web server.

I'm not sure what your configuration is like but try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="/campusdrinkthink.css" /> OR
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="/html/campusdrinkthink.css" />
```

PS: Your META tag is invalid. Not sure what you're trying to achieve there, but [have a read](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) at what it should look like.

Comment: I copied the link from my servers location to the file. Could I possibly post the code and see what I am doing incorrectly?<head><meta Campus DrinkThink/>
  <title> Campus DrinkThink </title> 
  <!--this is the link to the style sheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="sftp://ec2-user@23.21.112.84/var/www/html/campusdrinkthink.css" />
 </head>

Comment: I'm sorry I am just a bit confused on what exactly you mean. :( Sorry I don't mean to be annoying. I really am trying to learn.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything from my CSS. :/ I've made sure they are both in the same file and have directed it to the html file on my server as you specified. I'm definitely at a loss

Comment: What's the URL you're testing with?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the index.html (or your html) and the css sheet in the same folder, then there is no need for the whole address, you can just call it by using:

```
<link href="campusdrinkthink.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If the css in a folder, then the call would be:

```
<link href="FOLDER/campusdrinkthink.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And so...

Comment: Are you sure your css sheet is in the server? Is it in the same folder as the html? Did you also upload the html?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that **sftp** schema is not supported by browser.

Try to open `sftp://ec2-user@23.21.112.84/var/www/html/campusdrinkthink.css` directly in your browser.

For example, Mozilla Firefox displays message:

```
Firefox could not define, how to open this address, because the protocol (sftp) is not assigned to any application.
```